# Cracking sound just before any music plays

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, cinnamon

Whenever some sound plays after pause or if a new sound plays, there is a cracking sound in the beginning (for a second or so).

I tried the following fix: [Crackling and delayed sound after upgrading to 18.04 - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033405/crackling-and-delayed-sound-after-upgrading-to-18-04)

Edit the file

```
nano /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

then find a line containing:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

modify this to become:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

---

But it didn't help even after a restart.

For example, when I play on Vlc this notification wav sound https://0x0.st/oiwJ.wav , there is a distinct cracking sound in the beginning. Also when I do `aplay Beep-SoundBible.com-923660219.wav` I get the same noise.

I am using Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.3 (also faced the same problem in 20.2). Any suggestions?

Comment: does it also occur playing the sound on plain alsa pcms with aplay ? If no : Does it also happen when playing directly on alsa devices (I mean not via any sound server) under vlc or audacity ?

Comment: @MC68020 Yes when I play on vlc this notification wav sound https://0x0.st/oiwJ.wav , there is a distinct cracking sound in the beginning. Also when I do `aplay Beep-SoundBible.com-923660219.wav` I get the same noise.

Comment: The sample you gave seems being sampled a 11025 Hz. Most probably not the default sample rate of your sound device. => Have you ensured (in its sound settings) that resampling is enabled in vlc ? Try aplay -r=11025 alternatively resample your .wav to the default sampling rate of your sound device.

Comment: @MC68020 I tried with 44 KHz sound https://0x0.st/oiwE.wav I am facing the same problem. Basically I have this problem with any sound.

Comment: OK then could you ensure than when launching the playing your system is not commuting from another audio source (even if silent). Can you completely exit from your DE, and retry with aplay -r under a raw tty console ?

Comment: @MC68020 I went to tty by pressing Alt + Ctrl  + F2. I used aplay to play the file. I am having the same problem. Is that what you wanted me to do?

Comment: But doing that way, you left all other apps / services & sound server running. I'd prefer no other apps / service / sound server running, the simplest way being to exit your DE completely.

Comment: And if that still does not output correctly, please post /etc/asound.conf (if existing) and $HOME/.asoundrc (if existing) as well as the output of aplay -L

Comment: @MC68020 How can I exit DE completely? Can you please suggest what I need to do for that?

Comment: Ha! Too bad! You are using a desktop manager that fires automatically after booting ? Pfff ! Then I won't be of any help for you, I neither use nor know these things.

Comment: @MC68020 I booted into tty without desktop environment. I got the same problem with the audio file. You asked for output of 3 things above please see it here: https://0x0.st/oiGA.txt

Comment: Good ! Now, could you try aplay --device=hw:CARD=PCH your.wav (if possible of 48Khz sample rate) and aplay --device=dmix:CARD=PCH your.wav (of whatever sample rate)

Comment: @MC68020 Getting same noise in both commands fro 48 KHZ and 44.1 KHz

Comment: OK then this sounds like some very raw level power switching issue. Still under your tty console, can you find the /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save file ? If yes then, as root echo "0" > /sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save then retry aplaying --device=dmix:CARD=PCH twice.